# How can I get my dog to stop burying her food?

Tags: dogs, diet, eating

My dog is a little under a year old and she usually just buries left over bits of meat we bring back from restaraunts (we don’t do it often but it used to be the only time she’d bury her food). She eats outside because she thinks the dog food inside is the cat’s but for the last two days she’s been burying all of her food. ALL of it. she’ll even save the treats we give her when we’re training and bury them later outside and inside the house. I’ve read that it could be because they’re stressed or want to save it for later, but how can I get her to eat?

Comment: if your dog realy have stopped eating you take her to the vet,dogs in general eat all they can and then hide the rest.

Comment: Food for humans, especially food cooked at a restaurant, has too much salt and spices for a dog. It's not healthy to feed such food to a dog.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not making food available all day. Make half her days portion of food available in the morning, and half at dinnertime. In addition, remove her food bowl after 30 minutes. If it's empty, fine. If it isn't empty, then so be it, she can eat the rest at the next mealtime. Your pup will learn to eat what and when she is fed.

If she continues to bury her food, consider cutting back on the amount that she is fed. If she is hungry when you feed her, she will be more likely to eat it.

p.s. Fresh water should be available 24/7.